# Make asp panel fill all the height of it's container height

Tags: asp.net, html, css, treeview, height

- I have a table and in the first td of the first tr I put a treeview and its container is asp panel.
- The problem is that its height changes according to data, 
  so I don't know how to make its container "the asp panel"  always fill all td height whatever the tree view height is.

  ```
                              <td style="background-color: #FFD700; text-align: top;">
                              <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" GroupingText="Nodes" Height="100%">
                                  <div align="left" style="width: 170px; text-align: top; overflow: auto; height: 100%;
                                      min-height: 100%;">
                                      <asp:TreeView runat="server" ID="treesiteMap" OnSelectedNodeChanged="SiteMapTree_SelectedNodeChanged"
                                          Style="text-align: left; margin-left: 0; margin-right: auto; padding-left: 0;
                                          padding-right: auto; position: static" meta:resourcekey="treesiteMapResource1">
                                          <HoverNodeStyle BackColor="LightBlue" />
                                          <SelectedNodeStyle BackColor="LightGray" />
                                      </asp:TreeView>
                                  </div>
                              </asp:Panel>
                          </td>
  ```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take the generated markup and create a test in http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1):

You can involve the controls inside the panel with a div and add the follow style, If you have other elements in the page, in example a menu, you can substract the heigh of the menu:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" ScrollBars="Vertical"  ClientIDMode="Static" >
        <div style="height:calc(100vh - 240px);">
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phPrincipal" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        </div>
    </asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the position style of your 'td' to 'position:relative' and then assigning the following CSS class to your panel:

```
.superPanel
{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
}
```

Checkout this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KodeKreachor/4LqFS/2/

Comment: thanks Kode fro your reply ,  but it makes the treeview goes to the top of page and out of the table.

Comment: Check out the fiddle I added to my answer, it demonstrates a relatively positioned td containing an absolutely positioned div which stretches to whatever height the td is.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use jquery and do the following:

First, include jquery in the head section of your page (here I'm putting the remotely hosted version, that you can copy and paste as it is).

```
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then, add an id to the div you want to resize and an id to the td which height will be your 'reference' (I called it "mydiv" and "mytd") :

```
                        <td id="mytd" style="background-color: #FFD700; text-align: top;">
                        <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" GroupingText="Nodes" Height="100%">
                            <div id="mydiv" align="left" style="width: 170px; text-align: top; overflow: auto; height: 100%;
                                min-height: 100%;">
                                <asp:TreeView runat="server" ID="treesiteMap" OnSelectedNodeChanged="SiteMapTree_SelectedNodeChanged"
                                    Style="text-align: left; margin-left: 0; margin-right: auto; padding-left: 0;
                                    padding-right: auto; position: static" meta:resourcekey="treesiteMapResource1">
                                    <HoverNodeStyle BackColor="LightBlue" />
                                    <SelectedNodeStyle BackColor="LightGray" />
                                </asp:TreeView>
                            </div>
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </td>
```

Finally,

add the following code in a  at the end of your body:

```
   //A generic function that resizes an element's height according to another's

   function resizeMydiv(targetElement,ReferenceElement) {

          targetElement.css("height",ReferenceElement.height());
          //Code means : the css height of TargetElement should be the height of ReferenceElement.

   }

   $(document).ready(function() {

          //I call my function, passing #mydiv and #mytd as the variables
          resizeMydiv($("#mydiv"),$("#mytd"));

   });

   //Optional : this calls the function again on window resize, to keep it proortional to the window size if needed.

   $(window).resize(function() {

          resizeMydiv($("#mydiv"),$("#mytd"));

   });
```

Comment: No offense, but wouldn't applying a couple CSS classes be simpler?

Comment: thanks Camille , it works but every action affects size , it keeps caling $(window).resize() till page hangs.